# Getting system specifications using softlayer api is same as probing the machine and fetching?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Softlayer has exposed REST APIs to get the system specifications like memory, disk etc. When we run the APIs, will it probe the machine and fetch the values or it will be based on the order template. I meant running df -h on the machine and fetching the same using softlayer API will be same? I want to write a validation script to check whether machine is provisioned as per the specifications provided or not. So I am looking for which option to use Softlayer API or run the commands on the machine and get the info.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API will probe the machine and fetch the values, I can suggest to use the following REST requests to get information about the servers:

**Virtual Servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/18078091/getObject?objectMask=mask[blockDevices, billingItem, datacenter, localDiskFlag, controlPanel, firewallServiceComponent, networkComponents, operatingSystem, softwareComponents, evaultNetworkStorage, hourlyBillingFlag, monitoringAgents, networkMonitors, networkStorage, antivirusSpywareSoftwareComponent, bandwidthAllocation, networkVlans]

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and 18078091 with your own values

**Hardware Servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/154931/getObject?objectMask=mask[hardDrives, activeComponents, billingItem, datacenter, controlPanel, components, firewallServiceComponent, networkComponents, operatingSystem, softwareComponents, evaultNetworkStorage, hourlyBillingFlag, monitoringAgents, networkMonitors, networkStorage, antivirusSpywareSoftwareComponent, bandwidthAllocation, networkVlans, driveControllers, memory, motherboard, networkCards, powerComponents, processors, remoteManagementComponent, uplinkNetworkComponents]

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and 154931 with your own values

References:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject)
- [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getObject)

I hope it helps